# Incorrect behaviour of poll system call in linux

Tags: c++, linux, system

While using poll system call i found a stange behaviour.
I have the following code snippet.

```
struct pollfd myPollfds[nCount];
ACE_Time_Value selectTime;
selectTime.set(60);

 myPollfds[0].fd = rtrrmEvent[0];
 myPollfds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLRDHUP | POLLHUP | POLLERR;
        myPollfds[0].revents = 0;

        myPollfds[1].fd = rtrfeEvent[0];
        myPollfds[1].events = POLLIN | POLLRDHUP | POLLHUP | POLLERR;
        myPollfds[1].revents = 0;

        myPollfds[2].fd = _h[msclient_pos];
        myPollfds[2].events = POLLIN | POLLRDHUP | POLLHUP | POLLERR;
        myPollfds[2].revents = 0;

        myPollfds[3].fd = holdTimeEvent[0];
        myPollfds[3].events = POLLIN | POLLRDHUP | POLLHUP | POLLERR;
        myPollfds[3].revents = 0;

        ACE_Time_Value sleepTime(0,20000);
        while(isRunning() && !_stopRequested)
        {
                ACE_OS::sleep(sleepTime);
                for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        myPollfds[i].revents = 0;
                waitResult = ACE_OS::poll (myPollfds, nCount, &selectTime);
                if(waitResult == -1) // poll failed
                {
                       DEBUG("%s", "poll failed");
                         continue;
                }
                else if(waitResult == 0) // Time out
                {
                        //Do something .
                }
                char nodata[256];

                for(short i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
  if(myPollfds[i].revents == POLLIN)
                        {
                                if(i == rtrrm_pos)
                                {
                                         // Stop channel
                                }
                                else if(i == rtrfe_pos) // 'rtrfe' command
                                {
                                        DEBUG("%s", "fe issued");

                                }
                                else if(i == msclient_pos || waitResult == 0)
                                {
                                      //Do something
                                }
                                else if(i == holdTime_pos)
                                {
                                        DEBUG("%s", "Hold issued");
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                DEBUG("polling failed with with myPollfds[i].revents == %d",myPollfds[i].revents);
                        }
```

The problem is that i get some times :
"polling failed with with myPollfds[i].revents == 0"
 :
"polling failed with with myPollfds[i].revents == 8193"

the poll call is not waiting for the fd's to set.
can any one help?

Comment: -1 for blaming linux.

Comment: I am not blaming Linux, i was qurious to know what i was doing wrong .. thats it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test is incorrect:

```
  if(myPollfds[i].revents == POLLIN)
```

It should probably (can't be sure because you removed all the logic) be:

```
  if((myPollfds[i].revents & POLLIN) != 0)
```

Also, seeing the "polling failed" message is perfectly normal. It just means there was no activity on that particular file descriptor. You are polling on more than one descriptor, right? So it's normal for some of them to have no activity.

Comment: ok i understand what you are saying but, the thing is even if there is no activity ongoing it should hit the Wait timeout part of the code. But I have never observed that.else if(waitResult == 0) // Time out
                {
                        //Do something .
                }

Comment: @samairtimer What happens when there is no activity?

Comment: when there is no activity .. i get myPollfds[i].revents = 8193 some value, which is not equivalen to POLLIN and hence the logic goes undefined.

Comment: So the bug is exactly what I said. `8193 & POLLIN` is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

As David said,

> "polling failed" message is perfectly normal.

in any case, when poll returns other than just POLLIN
for example:

```
poll ... = 1



{fd=8193, revents=POLLIN|**POLLHUP**}
if (POLLIN|POLLHUP == POLLIN)
```

is going into "else" clause.

I'm not so good in C, so I can't tell if David's "if statement" is correct or not.